# How to edit files using (pro)bot on GitHub?

Tags: typescript, github, bots, github-api, probot

I'm building a GitHub bot using `probot` framework for editing the README.md of the repository but so far I could not find a way to edit files using `probot` and neither using any other GitHub bot framework.

So is it possible to edit files using bots on GitHub? If yes please give me some tutorial links or references.

For example I want to add a specific line to the end of README.md on every commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find some info in this Github issue: https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/845#issuecomment-386108187

If you need help to implement the details I think you can look for existing issues or discussions opened in Octokit repos: https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/discussions/categories/q-a

Let me know if you still need help with that!

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding code for how I did it using `probot`, I did it with help of [@OscarDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3237248/)'s answer,
**Index.ts**

```js
import { Probot } from "probot";

export = ({ app }: { app: Probot }) => {
  app.on("issues.opened", async (context) => { // You can change the "issues.opened" according to your use
    var sha;
    var a = Buffer.from("ABCd");
    var content = a.toString("base64");
    await context.octokit.repos
      .getContent({
        owner: "your_github_username",
        repo: "repo_name",
        path: "file_path",
      })
      .then((result) => {
        sha = result.data.sha;
      });
    await context.octokit.repos.createOrUpdateFileContents({
      owner: "your_github_username",
      repo: "repo_name",
      path: "file_path",
      message: "hilo",
      content: content,
      sha: sha,
    });
  });
```